# Is there a way to return the current page in a dashTable?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I have a dashtable with different pages (`pagination = True`) because it has over 5000 records, and the page loads very slowly when I use, for example, `page_size=5000`. I made a def that returns the contents of the row when clicked with more details from the sqlite database I’m using.

Here is the base code:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('popup-container', 'children'),
    [Input('table', 'selected_cells'),
     Input('table', 'derived_virtual_data'),
     Input('my-dropdown', 'value'),
     ],
)
def update_popup(sel, current_table, value):
    if sel:
        column_name = sel[0]['column_id']
        row_num = sel[0]['row']
        valor = current_table[row_num][column_name]
        print(valor)
        print(current_table)
```

Where ‘popup-container’ is a Div, ‘table’ is the dashTable and ‘my-dropdown’ is a dropdown that doesn’t interfere. Sel is a variable that gets the selected_cell row.

This def is working fine for the first page of the dashtable. However, when I change pages the current_table variable returns only the first page of the table. How can I make the current_table return the current page data?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is what you need](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/callbacks). The docs go over how to handle pagination on the back end. Not only does it help you speed things up in the browser by loading only what you need, but you can get the `page_current` prop as an input for your callback.